# Material UI Autocomplete - How do I add the same icon + text to the Textfield after I have selected

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So I'm currently trying to use Material UIs Autocomplete component but I am unable to have the selected item from the dropdown appear in the Textfield with the same icon.

This image is what I want (The dropdown icon + text is in the textfield)
[image: This is the image that I want]

This is what I currently have: (As you can see, I am unable to render the icon aswell)
[image]

How can I adjust my Autocomplete component to do this?
This is my Autocomplete component:

```
<Autocomplete
    options={components}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.description}
    renderTags={options => 
    {
      return (
          options.map(option =>
            <Box component="li" sx={{ '& > img': { mr: 2, flexShrink: 0 } }}>
              <img src={option.logo} style={{ height: "20px", width: "20px", marginRight: "10px" }}/>
            {option.description}
          </Box>))
    }}
    renderOption={(props, option) => (
      <Box component="li" sx={{ '& > img': { mr: 2, flexShrink: 0 } }} {...props}>
        <img src={option.logo} style={{ height: "20px", width: "20px", marginRight: "10px" }}/>
        {option.description}
      </Box>
    )}
    renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField 
            {...params}
            variant="outlined" 
            label="Select component" 
         />
    )}
/>
```

How do I also make it search by just the text and not have the icon interfere?

NOTE: I was able to do it with the MUI Select component, but that component is not searchable, in which I need it to be.. hence trying to use Autocomplete..

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the state responsible for the selected value of this `Autocomplete` component contains the whole selected object, you could achieve the icon at the start of the input by setting `startAdornment`  prop of the `TextField` component:

```
const [option, setOption] = useState<OptionType | null>(null)

    <Autocomplete
      value={option}
      renderInput={(params) =>  <TextField {...params} 
        InputProps={{...params.InputProps, 
        startAdornment: <img src={option.logo} style={{ height: "20px", width: "20px", marginRight: "10px" }}/>}} 
      />}
    />
```